# How does the text becomes clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this text from this json text. I want to make the text "is" clickable so as to show a drop down menu when i click on the word. The drop down should show the three links home, about and contact. and they should be clickable too so that the text "is" becomes some other color when i click an item on the drop down menu.

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: the clicking is not working. whenever i click on the "is", it doesn't do anything

Comment: Just altered it above so it runs and it is working fine.

Comment: it's showing the dropdownenu but when i click on home or about, it isn't changing the color of "is" in John is good. I want that to occur too

Comment: well there is no code that does that.... so you need to add event listeners to those elements and change the text or color.

Comment: yeah i mean can you show it to me how to do that with event listeners like the one we used here for showing the drop down menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some code to your original, try below snippet please:

```js
var myJSON = '{"name":"John", "determinant": "is", "adjective":"Good"}';
    var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = myObj.determinant;
    document.getElementById("new").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = myObj.adjective;

    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
      if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
        var color;
        var _href = event.target.getAttribute('href');
        switch (_href) {
          case '#home':
            color = 'yellow';
            break;
          case '#about':
            color = 'Aqua';
            break;
          case '#contact':
            color = 'Magenta';
            break;
          default:
            color = 'red';
        }
        document.getElementById("new").style.color = color;
      }
    }
```

```css
.dropbtn {
      background-color: #3498DB;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropbtn:hover,
    .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #2980B9;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .show {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Convert a string written in JSON format, into a JavaScript object.</h2>

  <span id="demo"></span> <span id="new" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()"></span> <span id="city"></span>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
```

Is that what you need ? :)

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is what I needed exactly